# get the message if send email failed C# and gmail

Tags: c#, email, gmail

I know this is popular question, searched around and I confused which way to do.
Basically I have this :

```
            try
            {
                smtpServer.Send(myMailMessage);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "aaa");
                output.WriteLine(line);
            }
```

And if the email fails to send, I can see it if I check my gmail for Delivery has failed . But It writes nothing to console and the output file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only logical explanation is that the exception being thrown is not `SmtpFailedRecipientsException` and thus your catch block never fires. Try catching a broader `Exception` as a test and inspecting it while debugging.

Comment: I under stand that it never fires, any ways to wait for the server to send email and get the result? I don't really get your answer

Comment: Have you tried catching `Exception e` and seeing if it works?

Comment: There's the concept of e-mail errors that happen at the point where you send it to *your* mail server, then the concept of errors that happens when your mail server sends the actual message *to the recipient*. You can't really catch the failure of messages sent to the recipient programmatically unless you own and control the mail server yourself.